# AnimationListener inside method

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm working on an older project, and now I'm stuck a little bit.

I have 9 buttons on one layout, and they all are connected to their methods who call their `Intents`.
Like this.. `button 1`

```
public void button1_click(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Btn1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now I after a couple of years, I want to implement an simple animation where the button will do something (whats the animation it's irrelevant).

Now in my Animation method - `startAnimation`

```
private void startAnimation(final View view){
       final Animation wigle = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
       view.startAnimation(wigle);
       wigle.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


            }
        });

}
```

I want to wait for the animation to finish and then to start my intent.

The `button 1` with this method looks like

```
public void button1_click(View view){
    startAnimation(view);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Btn1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But my application starts the animation and then starts the `Intent`.
What should I implement to not to implement `setAnimationListener` to all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
 private void startAnimation(final View view){
    final Animation wigle = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);
    view.startAnimation(wigle);
    wigle.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.btn1_id:
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Btn1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2_id:
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Btn2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                .......
                ............
                ......
            }
        }
    });

}
```

use method as

```
public void button1_click(View view){
    startAnimation(view);
    disableAllButtons();    
}
```

Comment: I tough of this before, but I think it's still to much code... 
Any easier way?